# How to create a trap for properties on a constructible JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, javascript-proxy

Proxy has a [trap for `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/construct), which in theory should allow us to create Proxies that pass constructor arguments through to the target object. Example of how it works looks like this:

```js
function monster1(disposition) {
  this.disposition = disposition;
}

const handler1 = {
  construct(target, args) {
    console.log('monster1 constructor called');
    // expected output: "monster1 constructor called"

    return new target(...args);
  },
  
  get(...args) {
    console.info('get trap triggered!')
  }
};

const proxy1 = new Proxy(monster1, handler1);

const instance = new proxy1('fierce')

console.log(instance.disposition);
// expected output: "fierce"

console.log(instance.unknownProp);
// expected output: "get trap triggered!" <-- doesn't happen
```

This works perfectly. Except that `instance.unknownProp` now doesn't trigger `get` trap anymore.  How do I intercept properties now?

Comment: The trap is for property accesses on `proxy1` itself, like `proxy1.unknownProp`. To trap property accesses on the instance, you'll need to create a new proxy in the `new` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `Construct` you have `return new target(...args);`. That creates a new JS object, without any proxies set.

You should set an additional proxy on the newly created object to intercept property access there.

Like this:

```js
function monster1(disposition) {
  this.disposition = disposition;
}

const handler1 = {
  construct(target, args) {
    console.log('monster1 constructor called');
    // expected output: "monster1 constructor called"

    const obj = new target(...args);

    // Return a Proxy instead of object. 
    // We may use the same handler1 here, or we can
    // create another handler with `get`. Both work,.
    return new Proxy(obj, handler1);
  },
  
  get(...args) {
    console.log('get trap triggered!')
    return Reflect.get(...args);
  }
};

const proxy1 = new Proxy(monster1, handler1);

const instance = new proxy1('fierce')

console.log(instance.disposition);
// expected output: "get trap triggered!"
// expected output: "fierce"

console.log(instance.unknownProp);
// expected output: "get trap triggered!"
```

Comment: Omg, this is getting intricate

Comment: What does `Reflect.get(...args)` do in there? Or how does it know what to do?

Comment: @jayarjo, `Reflect.get(...args)` returns object property. It accepts object as a first argument and property name as a second argument. Proxies' `get` trap signature is `get: function(target, prop, receiver)`, thus allowing short syntax in the code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried, but I think `super` is your answer. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_class_super.asp

Comment: How exactly one would use a super in this context? You risk getting downvoted with such answers you know :)